# Help in understanding resonance in 1/4 wavelength detector / S parameters

Tags: rf, transmission-line, microwave, resonance, s-parameters

So this might be long question that requires some literature review but I will try condense it as much as possible such that hopefully I can get some help without the reader having to review the related paper.

So I will start off by saying that I am involved in a honours thesis in which I need to come up with a design that replaces a certain component. In this case that component is a stepped impedance filter(SIF)/(Bragg mirror).

These seem to be used interchangeably as I see the effectively produce the same outcome. This Bragg mirror is one component used in an overall system called a kinetic inductance parametric amplifier (KIPA). Now my task is to design a filter that has a smaller footprint than that of the SIF/brag mirror yet still produce the same overall functionality of the KIPA.

I will include a picture here for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wShi2.jpg So I am only interested in the purple box area. This includes the bragg mirror/SIF galvanically connected to a 1/4 wavelength resonator.

Lack in my understanding: My undertanding of the basic principles of how the microwave enegineering works is that the bragg mirror/SIF effectively acts as a mechanism to "trap" the signal we want to amplify in the 1/4 wavelength resonator for a longer duration allowing further amplification or I guess a higher quality factor Q. This 1/4 wavelength resonator is shorted to ground on the other side.

The signal that we want to resonate in the 1/4 wavelength resonator is 7.2GHz and the pump signal for PA is double that 14.4GHz All of this is designed in a CPW structure. (This is getting lengthy so I may include the paper i'm working off if anyone is kind enough to skim the parts that I may have missed. Now I have designed a CPW filter that has a notch at 7.2GHz through sonnet to replace that of the bragg mirror. My understanding is that if it is to produce a similar effect as the brag mirror then we need the |S11| = 0dB at 7.2GHz or close to meaning that it will reflect the desired signal and trap it in the resonator for longer as does the bragg mirror. Design with |S12| : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl0PW.jpg |S11| graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nZOo.jpg

I thought this would be enough information to deduce that this design should at least emulate the affect of the SIF/Bragg mirror and thus be a viable substitute. I have been told by my advisor that the |S11| parameter is not useful in making such a conclusion and that I have not shown that this filter connected with the 1/4 resonator will even perform resonance.

Would someone kind enough please if they have the time explain to me why this is not the right conclusion and that I need to simulate this filter with the 1/4 resonator attached. I've also been told if it does not resonate then try open circuited 1/4 or try 1/2 wavelength etc until resonance occurs.